# Significant Delay between Cloudwatch Alarm Breach and Alarm State Change

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an alarm configured to trigger if one of my target groups generates >10 4xx errors total over any 1 minute period. Per AWS, Load balancers report metrics every 60 seconds. To test it out, I artificially requested a bunch of routes that didn't exist on my target group to generate a bunch of 404 errors.

As expected, the Cloudwatch Metric graph showed the breaching point on the graph within a minute or two. However, another 3-4 minutes elapse until the actual Alarm changes from "OK" to "ALARM".

Upon viewing the "History" of the alarm, I can see a significant gap between the date range of the query, of almost 5 minutes:

```
"stateReasonData": {
  "version": "1.0",
  "queryDate": "2018-12-11T21:43:54.969+0000",
  "startDate": "2018-12-11T21:39:00.000+0000",
  "statistic": "Sum",
  "period": 60,
  "recentDatapoints": [
    70
  ],
  "threshold": 10
```

If I tell AWS I want an alarm triggered if the threshold is breached on 1 out of 1 datapoints in any 60 second period, why would it query only once every 5 minutes? It seems like such an obvious oversight. I can't find any possible way to modify the evaluation period, either.